# Terminal en Linux Mint y Code::Blocks

Tags: c

Tengo una duda, cosa que me arruina todos mis programas. Tengo Linux Mint y  edito en CodeBlocks. Cuando ejecuto mis programa, por ejemplo:
`#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

```
 int main()
{
 int n;
 printf("Introduzca el número de elementos en el arreglo:\n");
 scanf("%d\n",&n);
 int i,x[n];
 printf("Introduzca los %d elementos:\n",n);
 for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     scanf("%d\n",&x[i]);
 printf("Los elementos del arreglo son:\n");
 for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     printf("%d\t",x[i]);
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}
```

`
Mi da por salida:
Introduzca el número de elementos en el arreglo:
6

2

Introduzca los 6 elementos:
9
1
3
5
6
7
Los elementos del arreglo son:
2   9   1   3   5   6

Esto es raro porque cuando me dice que introduzca los elementos del arreglo, yo le puse 6 y ENTER y nada pasó; luego agregue el 2, por ejemplo (pudo haber sido otro número) y le di otra vez ENTER y ahora si se puso: Introduzca los 6 elementos. Puse los 6 elementos (del 9 a 7) ¡y me imprimió del 2 (que era el número que me permitía avanzar al siguiente paso del programa) al 6, ignorando el 7!
Me podría ayudar con esto.  Es muy importante para mi porque me pasa en todos mis programas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tu error está en la función `scanf()`, ya que estás insertando un salto de línea con `\n`. Este tipo de "funcionalidad" no la debes implementar en las funciones de entrada de datos (`scanf()`), sino en las de salida (`printf()`). Por lo demás lo tienes correcto.

El código te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int n;
     printf("Introduzca el número de elementos en el arreglo:\n");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     int i,x[n];
 
     printf("Introduzca los %d elementos:\n", n);
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
         printf("array[%d]: ", i);
         scanf("%d",&x[i]);
     }
     
     printf("Los elementos del arreglo son:\n");
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         printf("array[%d]: %d\n", i, x[i]);
     
     printf("\n -- FIN DE PROGRAMA --");
 
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Si me ayudo. Esa era la solución. Gracias, gracias.

Comment: @Mario3 Esto es ilegal en C: `int x[n]` y se llama [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#Implementation). Por cuestiones de portabilidad, no lo utilice, en su lugar, use memoria dinámica con [malloc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Comment: Si funciona esa asignación, pero es como pseudo dinámico. Pero si es mejor la opción que dices. muchas gracias

Comment: @Mario3 No es una solución estándar, todo dependerá del compilador que utilices. Es mejor seguir el estándar de C para no llevarse con la sorpresa de que no funciona en otro compilador. Otra razón para no usar los VLAs, es porque puede desbordar fácilmente el stack... el stack es mas limitada.

Comment: Muchas gracias Dave. Eso ayudará mucho para no preocuparme porque no jalen bien mis programas. Entonces es mejor usar el arreglo como un apuntador.

Comment: Yo a veces me pregunto quién vota negativo a una respuesta que es correcta. No es la primera vez que pasa, y me da la sensación de que no será la última.